# Is there a way to get a tree of objects currently in GPU memory in Pytorch?

Tags: debugging, pytorch, gpu

So I try to clear up my GPU memory, yet something is stuck in there. How to  get a tree of objects currently in GPU memory with Pytorch?

Comment: As far as I know, it's impossible. But you can start by looking at python objects alive (using sth. like `gc.get_objects()`, `locals()`, `globals()`)